# Laminas\Mail\Protocol\Exception\RuntimeException "Authentication Failed"

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, credentials

I'm order the product and proceed to checkout then show the error. I'm use the "zoho credentials" after that i remove the "zoho credentials". and use the gmail Own smtp but still error is coming. could be any suggestion please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can review the SMTP configurations, especially, the authentication type for the SMTP server connection: NONE , PLAIN, or LOGIN and the verification type for the server security certificate: SSL or TLS

For Magento 2.4.6, it resolves my issues in this regard, https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/systems/communications/email-communications.html?lang=en